dnsmasq with round-robin always returns the same address
I am on 24.04 with dnsmasq running on it. I want the dns clients get different IP addresses each time they query the same record. For detail, I try to load the balance of different wireguard clients to two servers. I make the clients go to a single dns record, and have the dnsserver round-robin the requests among two wireguard servers.
Here's my /etc/hosts file.
192.168.77.72 wgserver.example.com wgserver
192.168.77.71 wgserver.example.com wgserver

After that, I changed the client's config so that their nameserver is the server the above config is running.
When I dig the record twice, I get two different IP addresses, as expected.
vagrant@worker:~$ dig wgserver.example.com +short
192.168.77.71
192.168.77.72
vagrant@worker:~$ dig wgserver.example.com +short
192.168.77.72
192.168.77.71

But, when I try to ping, or wg-quick up wg0, they always resolve the same IP address. How should I change my config, so that every ping or every dns query return different IP address?
Note: I tried flushing dns-cache with no luck.
Another note: I know that this is not an ideal case or solution for load-balancing. However, the task I have requires me to follow these steps.
